# MFC Picture Control is not scaled automatically according to Windows display scale

Tags: c++, mfc, dpi

I have a Picture Control in my application which is not scaled properly according to the Windows zoom - 100, 125, 150 % etc.
I have done a research but only found a solution for C#, which is handled by a property `AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;` 
Can anyone tell me what is the alternative in MFC?

Comment: [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

MFC applications automatically default themselves to be DPI aware, this means that it assumes any resizing for bitmaps etc will be handled by the app (e.g. the app may have multiple versions of the same bitmap depending on DPI settings). It makes the app look much neater on scaled machines because the alternative is to automatically scale the whole app which can make it look 'fuzzy'.

You can switch OFF DPI awareness, have a look at this article:

[MFC applications now default to being DPI-aware](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/11/mfc-applications-now-default-to-being-dpi-aware.aspx)